# Render an action that returns a partial view in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have an action that returns an rendered asp.net mvc control and send it as a response for AJAX request.

I want to have the response of that action during  the whole page is rendering in a view.

```
public class Controller
{
  ....

  public ActionResult AjaxAction(string parameter)
  {
    return PartialView("~/Views/Controls/Control.ascx",parameter);
  }
}
```

now in view that renders the whole page I want something like:

```
<%var par = "1";%>
<%= AjaxAction(par) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve [partial requests](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/) may work for you. This is typically useful where your control is some form of 'widget'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jQuery load function, fired when the document is ready, and load the partial view into a div.

```
$(function() {
   $('#partialResult').load( '<%= Url.Action( "AjaxAction", "Controller", new { parameter = "1" } ) %>' );
}

 <div id="partialResult">
 </div>
```